# no result after transforming postgres query to jpql in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to write a query to fetch list as this query is native sql query, all I need is to transform to spring jpql in which I am failing badly. if there is any link related to this please let me know

I am supposed to get list from this query. as this query is working fine with postgres console but when I even tried this with spring jpa as native query 
it is showing results in console but not fetching in service layer [edit:] I mean not calculating any result set.

I am sure I am missing some important/small thing here.

below is the native postgres query

```
selcet t.id,count(*), count(*) filter (where t.status = 'DONE') from table t where t.id in ([list]) group by t.id
```

what Im trying is

```
SELECT t.id, count(t), count(t.id) where staus = 'DONE' from Table t where t.id in ([list]) group by t.id
```

edit: with constructor based query this is not even working

I am not even sure how to start this query

while being new to this I am not even able to start how to solve this.
Any hint, insight will be useful

Comment: typo staus in second query

Comment: ok i solved it by using projectionDTO btw thanks

Comment: @user7036414, post your answer here and accept it :)